# Docker Container cannot connect to other Container in same Network when deployed on a GCP Compute Engine, but works locally

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, pytest, google-compute-engine, playwright

I am currently trying to set up automated End-to-End testing for our website with Playwright and Pytest. I tested everything locally, everything works. For context, the website runs on two docker containers, one for the server and one for the app itself. I am using a 3rd docker container to run the tests, which is the docker container provided by playwright. I created a docker network so all 3 containers run via the same network.

This is my startup script:

```
docker network create -d bridge sherlock_mycroft_umbrella_testing

docker build -t server-testing-image ../server/. & docker build -t app-testing-image ../. & docker build . -t "playwright_testing"

docker run -t -d --name server_testing \
    -p 10101:443 \
    --dns 10.x.x.x --dns 172.x.x.x --dns 8.8.8.8 \
    -e H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
    -e H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET=${H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET} \
    -e H2O_WAVE_PORT=:443 \
    -e H2O_WAVE_ADDRESS=http://localhost:443 \
    -e ENVIRONMENT=dev \
    -e H2O_WAVE_DOMAIN=http://localhost:10101 \
    -e OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    -e OIDC_CLIENT_ID=IDIDIDIDIDIDIDID \
    -e OIDC_PROVIDER_URL= \
    -e OIDC_END_SESSION_URL= \
    --network=sherlock_mycroft_umbrella_testing \
    server-testing-image \
    tail -f /dev/null

docker run -t -d --name app_testing \
    --dns 10.x.x.x --dns 172.x.x.x --dns 8.8.8.8 \
    -e H2O_WAVE_APP_ADDRESS=http://app_testing:8000 \
    -e H2O_WAVE_ADDRESS=http://server_testing:443 \
    -e H2O_WAVE_DOMAIN=http://localhost:10101 \
    -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/wave-app-creds.json \
    -e TOKIO_CERTS=/app/tok_io/certs/brtokio_bundle.pem \
    -e H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
    -e H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET=${H2O_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET} \
    -e GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER=137xxxxxxx60 \
    -e OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    -e OIDC_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --network=sherlock_mycroft_umbrella_testing \
    app-testing-image \
    tail -f /dev/null

docker run \
    -e AUTOMATED_TESTING=true \
    --network=sherlock_mycroft_umbrella_testing \
    playwright_testing

if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then    docker stop server_testing & docker stop app_testing
        docker ps -a
        exit 1
else    docker stop server_testing & docker stop app_testing
        docker ps -a
        exit 0
fi
```

And this is the docker file for the playwright container:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.41.0-jammy

COPY . /testing
WORKDIR /testing

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN playwright install chromium --with-deps

CMD xvfb-run -a pytest
```

When I run everything locally, everything works, but as soon as I do it on the compute engine, it says that it couldn't connect to "http://server_testing:443". Everything else works so far though. I already looked into the gcp firewall settings, but the ip address of server_testing_443 is included in the allowed IP range and the port is also enabled. So what could be the problem here? What did I oversee?

Comment: Is it a problem that you're telling the first two containers to run `tail -f /dev/null` instead of their normal commands?